# How to set the adapter for an inner RecyclerView item without skipping the layout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I'm using a `RecyclerView` to display some data. For each item in my RecyclerView I have created a custom layout which holds beside other views a RecyclerView. So I have a nested RecyclerView under each item.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>

    //Other text views
</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout for the inner RecyclerView is very simple, an ImageView for each item, like in the screenshot below:

[image]
This is my adapter class for the outer ReyclerView:

```
class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View itemView;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.itemView = itemView;
        recyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    }

    void bind(User user) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            //Move to user Activity
        });

        UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(user.list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm creating a new `UserAdapter` object for each `RecyclerView` that exist within my item so each inner RecyclerView to have its own adapter. Unfortunately I get:

> No adapter attached; skipping layout

How to set the adapter for the inner RecyclerView, so I cannot get this error anymore? Can it be set outside my outer adapter class? Thanks!

**Edit:**

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder userViewHolder, int position, @NonNull User user) {
    userViewHolder.bind(user);
}
```

Comment: You should add `LinearLayoutManager` before the setting adapter to recyclerview

Comment: I already do this using: `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, false));`

Comment: So what is your problem? Is your recyclerview not correctly work? or you just want to avoid this message?

Comment: Is working but I want to get rid of that message. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: What is this void bind(User user) method. I have never seen it. Have you created this method?

Comment: @RohitSingh Yes, I have created it to simply call `userViewHolder.bind(user)` in my  `onBindViewHolder()` method. Please check my updated question. Do you have any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Generally we get this warming message when the recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter) is being called with some delay. Say you are parsing list it in some other thread and after parsing you call it. Is this the case with you ?

Comment: Yes it is calling with some delay but in my case but I'm not getting the data from a list but from a `FirestorePagingOptions` object which is passed to my adapter.

Answer (score 1):

What about doing like this:

```
class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

   View itemView;
   RecyclerView recyclerView;
   UserAdapter adapter;

   UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
       super(itemView);
       this.itemView = itemView;
       recyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
       adapter = new UserAdapter(user.list);

       itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        //Move to user Activity
       });
       recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

   }

   void bind(User user) {

       adapter.setUser(user);            // update you adapter dataset here
       adatper.notifyDataSetChanged();

   }
}
```

So, `void bind` is used only to update the adapter dataset...

Comment: That's more like it.

Comment: So you say that I should create the adapter in constructor and not in the my method? What's the point since the constructor is also called with some delay?

Comment: @RohitSingh This answer is what you also tried to explain? It makes no sense. Please see also my comment above.

Comment: Yeah this does not make sense. However point being that you should pass an empty list and setAdapter(Readily available) and then update the adapter with the updated list(Delay) @JohansBormman

Comment: If you create your adapter in the constructor, it will be created only once per holder. The bind method is called each time you scroll your list and a new item appears on the screen. So, you are recreating the adapter continuously and this is not needed. Only the dataset should be updated. This will update the list faster.

Comment: @Ferran `adapter.setUser(user);` what does it mean? And also there is no `user.list` in the constructor.

Comment: `adapter.setUser(user)`is a `public void' that you should add to your adapter class. Just for updating the user list. You are right, the constructor should be `adapter = new UserAdapter();`. The list should be set only in `adapter.setUser(user);`.